# OpenVPN охватывает все порты?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Стоит клиент invisible browser, обычный платный VPN.
Он поднимает OpenVPN udp.

Это охватывает все порты или только 8080?
То есть весь ли трафик маршрутизируется через vpn-мост?
Как это узнать?

Answer (score 2):

Уточню ответ и объясню некоторые тонкости.

Ответ на первый вопрос - ДА, OpenVPN охватывает все порты. Но есть один нюанс. Есть такое понятие таблица маршрутизации ([что это?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) wiki). В Windows её можно посмотреть через "Коммандную строку",  запущенную от имени администратора. В ней нужно набрать `route print`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выполнения вы увидите много информации, в том числе и `IPv4 таблица маршрутов`. Это то, что нам нужно.

VPN соединение создает дополнительный интерфейс для себя, а потом, **в зависимости от настроек** направляет пакеты через этот интерфейс. Его адрес сразу можно будет узнать в окне информации OpenVPN и сопоставить с графой `Интерфейс`.

После этого, система направляет пакет попавший на интерфейс по таблице маршрутизации на следующий этап (шлюз). Это то устройство, которое примет пакет и отправит ещё дальше...

На картинке отмечен стрелочкой стандартный маршрут, через который **ВСЕ** без исключения пакеты попадают на интерфейс `192.168.0.104`, а потом направляются через шлюз `192.168.0.1`.

**ТЕПЕРЬ САМОЕ ИНТЕРЕСНОЕ**

На основании `Сетевого адреса` и `Маски сети` (см. изображение) система определяет каким шлюзом воспользоваться для отправки пакета. Если указаны `0.0.0.0` и `0.0.0.0` — будет использоваться шлюз `192.168.0.1` для любого направления.

Как это применить к Вашей ситуации? Очень просто. Посмотрев таблицу маршрутизации Вы определите все ли пакеты отправляются через этот шлюз, или только пакеты, предназначенные для некоторых сетей. Например Сетевой адрес и Маска сети `10.11.12.0 255.255.255.0` будут говорить нам, что пакеты, предназначенные для сети с адресами `10.11.12.1-254` будут направлены через OpenVPN соединение.

Поэтому нужно внимательно смотреть настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Охватывает все. А трафик в зависимости от настроек сервера(можно просто сетку поднять а трафик вообще идти не будет кроме локального ). проверьте например через http://www.ip2location.com/ какой у вас ip и все сразу станет ясно, если ип VPN-сервера то все проходит, а если ваш, то меняйте настройки на стороне сервера